# Python, if substring in string don't contain any [a-zA-Z0-9_] at the begining of the substring

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a string called programs_cache that contains multiple program names and descriptions:

```
abcde - A Better CD Encoder
abcm2ps - Translates ABC music description files to PostScript (or SVG)
abcmidi - converter from ABC to MIDI format and back
abcmidi-yaps - yet another ABC to PostScript converter
cd-discid - CDDB DiscID utility
cl-launch - uniform frontend to running Common Lisp code from the shell
cppcheck - tool for static C/C++ code analysis
grabc - simple program to determine the color string in hex by clicking on a pixel
gregorio - command-line tool to typeset Gregorian chant
```

And i want to have an IF statement that returns True when searching for a `program_name` that it is in the `programs_cache` string, but it shouldn't return True if the search didn't provided the full name.

For example:  a search of `abc` should return False but a search of `grabc` should return True.

I was trying this:
`if program_name+" " in programs_cache and not re.search([w]+program_name+" ",programs_cache):`

But I'm getting the error `NameError: global name 'w' is not defined`

The idea of using the `W` was in order to match ANY single character before the program_name.

As described in the basic patters:
w    matches a "word" character: a letter or digit or underbar [a-zA-Z0-9_]. 
It only matches a single character not a whole word.

I know that I'm using wrong the function re.search() and the basic pattern but i haven't figured out how to properly use it in this case.

Comment: Firstly, a regex pattern should be a string not a single-element list. Secondly, it's `r'\w'` not `'[w]'`. Thirdly, why not make a list or set of program names and check against that, rather than a string?

Comment: @jonsharpe the tutorial that i found was using [\w]. i used r'\w' and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `why not make a list or set of program names and check against that, rather than a string?` because programs_cache is the output of  `programs_cache=os.popen("command"), programs_cache=programs_cache.read()` which gives a sting. That output can be processed as John posted, but it is slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# do this once during program start
program_names = set(line.partition(' - ')[0] for line in programs_cache)

# do this for each lookup
if program_name in program_names:
    print "got it"
else:
    print "don't got it"
```

Comment: The solutions works good!, but i was making some tests and it is a little bit slower than using `if program_name+" " in programs_cache and not re.search(r'w'+program_name+" ",programs_cache):` so I'll still using my solution